# Julia getaddrinfo is giving a peculiar result

Tags: sockets, julia

I am following with the code here : [how-to-use-sockets-in-julia](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-use-sockets-in-julia)

```
using Sockets
hostName = "educative.io"
getaddrinfo(hostName)
```

is giving output :   2606:4700:8390:cce8:9176:428:59b9:6297

but If I run the inline code in the link:

```
The Host IP Address = 104.18.3.119
```

Why it is different.

What is this output :  2606:4700:8390:cce8:9176:428:59b9:6297 stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this output : 2606:4700:8390:cce8:9176:428:59b9:6297 stands for.

This is an [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) whereas 104.18.3.119 is an [IPv4 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#Addressing). The site is connected via the Cloudflare CDN and is reachable with multiple IPv4 and IPv6 adresses.

> but If I run the inline code in the link: ... [IPv4]... Why it is different.

Likely the environment where the code is executed has no IPv6 connectivity and thus will not lookup the IPv6 address. Instead only IPv4 is checked and the IPv4 address is returned.

Comment: How to get IPv4 address in Julia?

Comment: @Vinod: This is a different question and should be asked as a new one instead of asking in a comment. But a short look into the documentation points to [getipaddr](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Sockets/#Sockets.getipaddr)

Comment: getalladdrinfo(hostName) will give both the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses